# How to make a div at the bottom and fixed in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have made many searches but i did not find a similar case.

Context : I have a div (div-1) that contains another div (div-2). I want div-2 always inside and at the bottom of div-1, even when scrolling. More, div-2 has to be always VISIBLE even when scrolling in div-1.

I have tested position:fixed but div-2 goes out of div-1. I think the solution have to be written with jQuery but i don't know how to handle it

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

No need for JQuery, only CSS is needed:

Put `position: relative` on `div-1` and the following on `div-2`:

```
position: sticky;
bottom: 0;
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ynx0hpy4/2/

Comment: you need to pay attention to overlapping, and also the size of the div, so using this will not be enough

Comment: then OP should have added more details to his post :) this is how to make a div fixed at the bottom of another div

Comment: you are right, i simply say this for you so you may consider these details to make your answer more complete ;)

Comment: it would have been more complete if it had a code example that I could work off of, however the question is rather broad.

Comment: absolute position is not a good solution because div-2 has to be visible when div-1 is visible. If absolute position and div-1 heighter than the screen (need to scroll), div-2 is not visible and that's the problem.

Comment: @Jesse de Bruijne have you tried your solution. I dont think `position: absolute` will work.

Comment: @JojoLapin45 I have updated my answer based on your recent clarification

Comment: @JessedeBruijne i have tried your solution but it does not work : div-2 is not always visible : https://jsfiddle.net/ynx0hpy4/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: sticky` in your `.div-2` class as below:

```css
.div-1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
.div-2{
  position: sticky;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a turpis at nisi congue suscipit. Vestibulum lobortis aliquam nisl, in dictum dui blandit quis. Cras facilisis, sem et placerat dapibus, lectus leo bibendum enim, sed mollis eros mi at nibh. Nullam venenatis ultricies tortor, vel accumsan lacus ultrices in. Maecenas non ligula ut ex ultricies elementum. Suspendisse dictum odio sollicitudin, convallis neque non, facilisis sem. Mauris imperdiet fringilla nulla vitae auctor. Vivamus molestie ligula ac nisi luctus viverra. Sed vestibulum tortor in volutpat congue. In finibus, mi ut congue sollicitudin, velit lectus scelerisque enim, eget viverra dolor velit quis ex. Nam sodales, ex sit amet cursus porta, odio tortor fermentum lacus, ac semper lectus leo sit amet turpis.
  ligula ac nisi luctus viverra. Sed vestibulum tortor in volutpat congue. In finibus, mi ut congue sollicitudin, velit lectus scelerisque enim, eget viverra dolor velit quis ex. Nam sodales, ex sit amet cursus porta, odio tortor fermentum lacus, ac semper lectus leo sit amet turpis.
  <div class="div-2">Fixed</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth getting into Flex layouts.

```
.div-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Reference:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-7

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with just two `div`'s, but you can do it with three:

```css
* {margin: 0}

#div1 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#div2 {
  height: 50px;
  background: Salmon;
}

#div3 {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px); /* div1's height - div2's height */
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: Khaki;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div3">
    <p style="height: 1234px">content...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">bottom...</div>
</div>
```

Position `sticky` doesn't count because of the poor browser support it has at the moment.